# How to convert C++ union to C# struct

Tags: c#, c++, struct, unions

```
typedef struct _communicate_data
{
    unsigned  short     m_type;
    unsigned char m_response_result;
    union{
        struct request_set_integrity
        {
            char  m_version[32];
            char  m_installed_path[256];
        }REQUEST_INTEGRITY;

        struct _request_update
        {
            char m_install_dir[MAX_PATH];
            char m_unzip_dir[MAX_PATH];
        }REQUEST_UPDATE;    
        struct response_dna
        {
            int      m_len; 
            char m_dna[256];
        }RESPONSE_DNA;    
        struct request_setinfo
        {
            int m_len; 
            char m_host[128];
            char m_userid[64]; 
            char m_deviceid[128];
        }REQUEST_SETINFO;    
        char  m_reason[256];            
        struct response_realtime
        {
            int m_type;
            char m_path[256];
        }RESPONSE_REALTIME;    
        struct response_status
        {
            char m_dna_status;
            char m_realtime_status;
            char m_policy_status;
            char m_application_status;
            char m_login_status;
            char m_usb_status;
            char m_sendlog_status;
            char m_isolate_status;
            char m_mode;  
        }RESPONSE_STATUS;    
        struct response_version
        {
            unsigned short m_major_version;
            unsigned short m_minor_version;
            unsigned short m_build_version;
            unsigned short m_release_version;
        }RESPONSE_VERSION;    
        char  m_dbname[256];
        char  m_policyname[256];    
        struct request_set
        {
            DNA_PERFORMACE m_performace;
            XSP_RUN_MODE   m_mode;
        }REQUEST_SET;    
        struct response_compare
        {
            UINT  m_type;
            char m_path[MAX_PATH];
        }RESPONSE_COMP;
    }data;
}COMMUNICATE_DATA;
```

There is struct with union in C++, so task is to convert this struct to C# code. I am having to convert for 2 days. I cannot set [FieldOffset(0)] attributes correctly.

Can anyone help to convert this struct to union?
Thank you!

**EDIT**
This is my conversion to C# code. But it gives error "Additional information: Could not load type 'Common.dataunion' from assembly 'ProjectName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it contains an object field at offset 0 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field."

```
 public struct dataunion
        {       
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public request_set_integrity REQUEST_INTEGRITY;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public _request_update REQUEST_UPDATE;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public response_dna RESPONSE_DNA;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public request_setinfo REQUEST_SETINFO;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public byte[] m_reason;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public response_realtime RESPONSE_REALTIME;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public response_status RESPONSE_STATUS;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public response_version RESPONSE_VERSION;
            [FieldOffset(320)]
            public byte[]  m_dbname;
            [FieldOffset(320)]
            public byte[] m_policyname;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public request_set REQUEST_SET;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public response_compare RESPONSE_COMP;
        }
      [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct comData
        {      
            public ushort m_type;        
            public byte m_response_result;        
            public dataunion data;       
        }
```

Comment: There is no `FieldOffset` in your code. Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: @KyleKhalaf I updated question with some source code

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt653981.aspx). I believe that information there is understandable and I don't have to duplicate it here.
Good luck!

Comment: I followed above link and edit my code, but it still gives  error